# How to untracked files I have accidentally gotten Git to track

Tags: git, git-bash, rstudio

So I messed up big time when trying to add a R Project to Git. I typed the exact location of my R Project (in my Documents folder on my computer), and typed `git init`.

However, when I typed `git add .` it went FUBAR. I got a lot of error messages saying permission denied. I forced stopped it and then deleted the index file. However, when I opened it up again and typed `git status` it basically showed all of the folders under `C:\Users` under untracked files plus a bunch or error messages saying permission denied.  Nothing has been committed.

I've tried doing `git clean -f -d` as well as `git rm -r --cached`.

Comment: I think that worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Just posted it as an answer. If you found it helpful, please be sure to upvote it. And if it’s the answer that solved your issue, please be sure to check it off as such.

Answer (score 0):

## Don’t panic!

### Git is not tracking much of anything yet.

Find the hidden `.git` directory that should be in the directory you ran `git init` in and just delete that and you should be good to go.

That `.git` directory is what tracks everything in the directory it lives in. So deleting that will solve your problem.

The reason I know this will work is you clearly state:

> “…it basically showed all of the folders under `C:\Users` under untracked files…”

If the files are untracked then you have no reason to fear. You simply ran `git init` in a directory you shouldn’t have. You should only ever run `git init` from within the directory of code that you want to make a part of your repository